# MemoryError on Windows but not MacOS when using np.zeros

Tags: python, windows, macos, python-2.7, numpy

I want to build a numpy array but I get MemoryError in windows that has 16 GB RAM. To give more information the details are as follows:

```
Python 2.7.13 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:17:26) [MSCv.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

xx = np.zeros((110000,80000,3))

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
MemoryError
```

However exactly the same code runs on mac computer with 8 GB RAM. The details are:

```
Python 2.7.12 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (x86_64) [GCC 4.2.1 (LLVM build ... )on darwin)]

xx = np.zeros((1100000,8000000,3)) doesn't give error.
```

And when I increase the size at last I get error on Mac however the error is different as follows:

```
xx = np.zeros((1100000,80000000,3))
python(713,0x7fffa76b33c0) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=211200000000000) 
failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
MemoryError
```

How could I deal with this problem?

[image: This is the output from terminal]

Comment: Did you calculate how much memory that array needs? Thats MUCH more than you have available.

Comment: I know but why in mac I don't get that problem with even 100 times larger array size. I run both of these lines from command line and I don't get why there should be such a difference in these cases.

Comment: *"however the error is different as follows"*; I see the same error: `MemoryError`, which you could expect. If you need to solve a problem that requires much more memory than you system has, it is probably best to solve it in chunks that do fit in memory. Just to be clear: the array you are trying to create requires ~200GB memory!

Comment: My question is why in Mac I don't get that error when I define an array of size 110000*80000*3 as I get an error in Windows with higher configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Your array is too huge to fit in the physical RAM on both systems:

```
110000 * 80000 * 3 * 8 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 = 196.[69] GB
```

However it depends on your system how it deals with the memory-request and how it "stores" the memory. For example the system could simply "reserve" memory for your process but postpones the actual allocation until the memory is read/modified. And even if the memory is allocated the memory can be compressed (as noted in the comments, thanks @Martijn Pieters) and having lots of zeros can be compressed really well - however as soon as you modify the memory the compression will become less efficient and more "real memory" is used.

That means it's up to the system when it fails (both will eventually fail if you actually do something with the array). Windows in your case chooses to fail immediately when you request more physical memory than you have. On Mac it seems like you have to modify "enough" values (see also [this answer on "Why a 352GB NumPy ndarray can be used on a 8GB memory macOS computer?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54961554/5393381)) until it fails.

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.zeros((110000,80000,3))  # MemoryError on Windows
arr += 10                         # MemoryError on Mac
```

You could use for example `psutil` to check the amount of memory used (physical and virtual):

```
import psutil
print(psutil.virtual_memory())  
# svmem(total=4170924032, available=1666629632, percent=60.0, used=2504294400, free=1666629632)
arr = np.zeros((10000, 10000))
print(psutil.virtual_memory())
# svmem(total=4170924032, available=1664675840, percent=60.1, used=2506248192, free=1664675840)
arr += 10
print(psutil.virtual_memory())
# svmem(total=4170924032, available=864059392, percent=79.3, used=3306864640, free=864059392)
```

So even on Windows the `np.zeros` doesn't immediately "use" the physical memory until it is needed.

> How could I deal with this problem ?

The easiest (but probably most costly) option would be to buy (a lot) more RAM. But you could also try to "chunk" the processing with chunk sizes that fit into your physical memory. Ultimately the best solution would be to rethink your approach/algorithm so you don't need that much memory.

Comment: I don't get any error on Mac.

Comment: @salarrazavi Not even with the `arr[0, 0, 0] = 10` line? That would be weird, what about `arr[-1, -1, -1] = 100` or `arr+1`?

Comment: I uploaded the screenshot in the first post. Also the last element of the array can be defined by the way.

Comment: @salarrazavi I updated the answer :) Unfortunately I have no access to a Mac myself and thought it would behave like my linux VM...

Comment: Thanks for your time but I also don't get any error for arr[:].

Comment: @salarrazavi, I can't help with macOS, but in Windows a CRT `malloc` calls `HeapAlloc` (implemented as `RtlAllocateHeap` in the NT runtime library), which for such a large allocation calls [`NtAllocateVirtualMemory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff566416), once to reserve the region and then again to commit it (see [Page State](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366794)). The commit is charged against the system commit limit, based on the total RAM and paging files. The Task Manager's performance tab shows you the current and maximum committed memory.

Comment: On my Mac (with Python3), `x = np.zeros((110000,80000,3))` also directly fails with a `MemoryError`. But I still don't understand why anyone would want to work with arrays which are ~10x the size of the available memory......... As mentioned by multiple people now: "rethink your approach/algorithm"

Comment: @MartijnPieters I would've expected that especially chunked writes could be compressed nicely (at least if the memory writes are contiguous). It could also be that it's just "paged" lazy allocation (allocation only happens when a page is actually read/modified). I'm not really sure about these details because there's a lot of moving parts NumPy/Compiler/OS that could do "optimizations". Thanks again for the link, that's a really interesting (and confusing) topic! :)

Comment: Well, I was certainly wrong about the compressed memory assertions I made, as it only applies to pages in physical memory for inactive processes, e.g. not the virtual pages of the current process. MacOS is just really really relaxed about vm overcommitting.

Answer (score 1):

As already stated, your array is way too large to fit into physical memory on both machines.
But the point is that physical memory is only part of the memory that is typically available on moder systems, the other one being virtual memory.

I am not sure whether Windows version of NumPy is actually compiled to only use physical memory, this could be, but I find it unlikely.
So, probably, the reason why you your Mac can handle that array is that it is configured to have a much larger virtual memory (read *swap*) than the virtual memory (read *PageFile*) available on Windows machine.
Therefore, increasing the *PageFile* size on your Windows machine is likely to fix your issue.
However, this is far from ideal as the virtual memory is typically orders of magnitude slower than the physical memory.

Your best bet is to use an algorithm that can work on chunks, or, if that is not possible, you should use [`memmap`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html) arrays, which, to the least may allow to work in-place on disk, thus avoiding copy huge amounts of data back and forth.

Comment: I could solve the problem by increasing the virtual memory size. Thanks

Comment: @salarrazavi, that's not a practical solution. Programs assume random access to memory, and relying on a paging file that's 12 times larger than physical RAM will probably slow your system to a crawl.

Comment: Maybe I did not make myself clear enough, but the point of this answer was to elucidate on the origin of the two different behaviors, not to suggest increasing virtual memory as a solution to the underlying problem. I could not agree more with the recommendation about rethinking your approach.